# Assign Matrix slice in SymPy

Tags: matrix, slice, sympy

I would like to replace the value of a slice of a Matrix in SymPy. Explicitly, it would be something like

```
import sympy as sym
A = sym.Matrix(4, 4, range(16))
A[0, :] = [-1, -2, -3, -4]
```

But this returns an error

```
ShapeError: 
The Matrix `value` doesn't have the same dimensions as the in sub-
Matrix given by `key`.
```

In a more interesting example I would like to do something like

```
A[0, 0::2] = [-1, -2]
A[0, 1::2] = [1, 2]
```

alternating the odd and even columns.

**Question:** Is there any way of doing this in SymPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slicing of SymPy matrices works differently from NumPy arrays: `A[0, :]` is a matrix, not a 1D array. As [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#basic-manipulation) says:

> slices always give a matrix in return, even if the dimension is 1 x 1

So the assignment must be done accordingly:

```
A[0, :] = [[-1, -2, -3, -4]]         # a matrix with 1 row
A[:, 0] = [[-1], [-2], [-3], [-4]]   # a matrix with 1 column
A[:, 0] = sym.Matrix([3, 4, 5, 6])   # easier way to create a one-column matrix
```

Unfortunately, assigning into non-contiguous submatrices like `A[0, 0::2]` is not (currently) implemented: the method [copyin_matrix](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b713f05a25e5e7aa2158ae1c23fabcd08888eaa5/sympy/matrices/dense.py#L813) assumes the assigned block is contiguous.